# What is wrong with this AngularForEach statement?

Tags: angularjs, foreach

```
    $scope.inUserList = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.usernames, function(uname){
        if (uname.name == $scope.username){
            alert("WOOW");
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

The function that calls for this is:

```
$scope.addusername = function(){
    if ($scope.username && !$scope.inUserList()){
        $scope.usernames.push({name: $scope.username});
        //$scope.usernames[$scope.usernames.length - 1] = serverList.save({command: 'addUser'}, $scope.usernames[$scope.usernames.length - 1]);
        var currentUser = $scope.usernames[$scope.usernames.length - 1];
        angular.toJson(currentUser);
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/addUser', currentUser)
            .success(function(response) {})
            .error(function(response) {alert("Failed to post");});
        $scope.loggedIn = true;
    }
    if ($scope.username && $scope.inUserList()){
        alert("Welcome back");
        $scope.loggedIn = true; 
    }
    else{
        alert("Need a username");   
    }
};
```

Here's when the name is inputted in the html:

```
    <label> Log In: 
        <input type="text" ng-model="username">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="addusername() ; ToDoView()">
    </label>
```

The $scope.usernames is just a json object with one property "name". I can never get this expression to evaluate true and I don't understand why. My names are exactly the same as the ones that are in the database but the expression still evaluates as false.

Comment: You have a demo to replicate the issue? Different note: return true inside forEach will not break out of the loop.

Comment: Do I need to add a break; then?

And I can add more of the functions going on to the op

Comment: if (uname == $scope.username){

Comment: The problem with that method, Hank, is that the $scope.usernames is an array of JSON objects set up like {"name": "username"} so that they can work in a grails database, so if I don't access the name then I'm comparing an object to a string.

Comment: @Ajv2324 Try console logging `uname.name` and `$scope.username`. Regd: Break that wont work either. You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or traditional foreac if you want to break out of loop once you find the first match.

Comment: When doing the console.log, the name and the $scope.username are exactly the same.

Although, now that I think about it, if it's not breaking out after returning true, then it's probably going through, then getting to the end, getting out of the loop and returning false. You suggest Array.some?

Comment: @Ajv2324 Do you see your alert then ofcourse it is matching.  Yes you can use Array.some... and add pollyfill in MDN.

Comment: Just remembered that I am not seeing the alert, so I guess this is not the case

Comment: Are you sure you dont have leading /trailing spaces or anything... Try to replicate it with simple minimal example..

Answer (score 0):

`uname` would have that name field, then.  `uname.name` would probably be undefined.  Try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.usernames, function(name){
    if (name == $scope.username){
    ...
```

Comment: I should have added in my opening but the $scope.usernames is an array that holds objects with parameter "name".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it only involved changing my inUserList function and restarting my server. I still don't get the alert for some reason but it works as intended.

```
    $scope.inUserList = function(){
    var newUsername = $scope.username
    var flag = false;

    angular.forEach($scope.usernames, function(uname){
        if (uname.name == newUsername){
            flag = true;
        }
    });
    if (flag)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
```